# Add users to SP Group

Tags: web-services, groups

Is there a way to add bunch of users to a SP Group at once using web service?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774538(v=office.12).aspx

I have several variables (varApprovers; varTeamLeads; varVPs; varManagers) and would like to add these to a SP Group.

http:///_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx
AddUserCollectionToGroup method

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the [UserGroup.AddUserCollectionToGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.addusercollectiontogroup.aspx) web service call would work. The example in the link illustrates how a group of users (specified in a XML list) can be loaded into an UserGroup.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in web services only provide the functionality to add one user at a time.

You could, however, write your own web service that sites in your SharePoint environment to handle these type of requests.